# How to set label backcolor in VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net

Here is the code :

`Chess(z).BackColor = #FFFFFF`

It is not working, how to make it work :))

Comment: What is the type of Chess(z) ? Add some more information to your question...

Comment: Chess(z) is a label, i want to change the Backcolor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use color constants:

```
Chess(z).BackColor = Color.White
```

Or create a color value from color components

```
Chess(z).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(&HFF, &HFF, &HFF)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows Forms, you probably want [System.Drawing.Color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color_members.aspx).  You can either use the static property `White` or in the general case you can construct your own color using the `FromArgb` method.

If you are using WPF, you can achieve something similar by using `System.Windows.Media.Colors.White`, or constructing your own color using the FromRgb method on [System.Windows.Media.Color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.fromrgb.aspx).